# Array input overriding value of loop

Tags: arrays, c

I'll include the entire code just in case, but the uncommented section is what's misbehaving.
For some reason it accepts input up to element 5, but after that it sets the value of loop to be whatever the user inputs. Elements 0-5 work just fine, and I have another loop set up earlier which works fine, granted that one never reaches element 5

edit: I see what I did now. I used the same array again without adjusting the size of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 6
#define ARRAY_SIZE2 10

int main(void);
int main(void)
{
    int array [ARRAY_SIZE];
    int array2 [ARRAY_SIZE2];
    int loop;
    int loop2;


   /* for (loop = 0; loop < ARRAY_SIZE; loop++)   //prompt for ARRAY_SIZE number of integers and put them in the array
    {
        printf("\nEnter an integer:");
        scanf("%d", &array[loop]);
    }
    printf("\n\nThe original order:");
    for (loop = 0; loop < ARRAY_SIZE; loop++)   //prints the array out one line at a time
    {
        printf("\n%d", array[loop]);
    }
    printf("\n\nReverse order:");
    for (loop = ARRAY_SIZE - 1 ; loop > -1; loop--)  //prints the array in reverse order
    {
        printf("\n%d", array[loop]);
    }
    printf("\nMy name is Corbin King\n");*/

    for (loop = 0; loop < ARRAY_SIZE2; loop++)
    {
        printf("\nenter an integer:");
        scanf(" %d", &array[loop]);
        printf("%d", loop);
    }
     for (loop = 0; loop < ARRAY_SIZE2; loop++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[loop]);

    }
    /*for (loop = 0; loop < ARRAY_SIZE2; loop++)
    {
        for (loop2 = loop + 1; loop2 < ARRAY_SIZE2; loop2++)
        {
            if (array [loop] > array [loop2])
            {
            array2 [loop] = array [loop2];

            }


        }


    }
    for (loop = 0; loop < ARRAY_SIZE2; loop++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", array2 [loop]);
    }*/
    getch(); //The getch command waits until a user presses a key
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The array has 6 elements in it. When you input the 7th element, that's outside the array and overwrites some random variable. Is this surprising? What were you expecting to happen, when you wrote to the 7th element of an array that has 6 elements?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `array` has a size `ARRAY_SIZE`. You are only allowed to loop until `ARRAY_SIZE-1`, starting from `0`, where the loop control variable is used for the indexing. By using `ARRAY_SIZE2` in the controlling expression, you're essentially using an index which is out of bound, and accessing out of bound memory is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change the controlling expression of the `for` loop to `loop < ARRAY_SIZE`.

Comment: So then can I not have multiple constants?

Comment: @KingBlake you can't write to the 7th element (number 6) of an array that only has 6 elements.

Comment: Yes you can, as long as you respect the array dizer. If swap the constants in the whole code your program would work (you declare 10 and access up to 6).